# Ruby Array#Flatten реализация

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Пытаюсь самостоятельно реализовать работу метода flatten. Получилось выполнить реализацию при которой убираются все вложенные массивы.

```
a = [ 1, 2, [3, [4, 5] ] ]

def my_flatten(arr)
    arr.reduce([]) do |result, item| 
      item.is_a?(Array) ? result + my_flatten(item) : result << item
    end
  end

my_flatten(a) #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Не получается реализовать алгоритм при котором можно указывать уровень для рекурсии. Пример работы оригинального метода:

```
a = [ 1, 2, [3, [4, 5] ] ]
a.flatten(1) #=> [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def my_flatten(arr, max_depth = nil, current_depth = 0)
  arr.reduce([]) do |result, item|
    if item.is_a?(Array) && (max_depth.nil? || current_depth < max_depth)
      result + my_flatten(item, max_depth, current_depth + 1)
    else
      result << item
    end
  end
end
```